# Why aren't my Drag events being fired when I add the events to the DataTemplate or elsewhere?

Tags: c#, user-interface, uwp

I am working on a UWP app where I am dragging some items from a Grid into a StackPanel that contains a ListView. My objective is to display categories in the ListView, and recategorize dragged Grid items by dragging them onto the specified category.

The problem I am having is that when I drag a Grid item onto a ListView item, Drag events (DragLeave, etc) does not fire, I am not sure why. In general, it seems like no matter what event I associate to the ListViewItems, they will not fire. I have enabled CanDrag/CanDrop and events do fire onto the StackPanel, but not the item itself.

I have tried placing the events into the DataTemplate, the StackPanel itself, I have tried using XAML Behaviors, and I have tried using other events such as PointerEntered. I have also tried to add it to ListViewPresenter, but that hasnt worked either.

I can confirm that ListViewItems ARE being generated as expected, and all of my events I have set have only one line of code to print the name of the method to the Debug output (which has worked for me in the past) - Debug.Write("method name fired"); - which is not printing to the output when items are dragged over the ListViewItems.

```
<StackPanel
    x:Name="dropAreas"
    Grid.Row="1"
    Grid.RowSpan="3"
    Margin="40,40,40,40">
    <ListView
        x:Name="dropAreasList"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        x:FieldModifier="public"
        AllowDrop="True"
        ItemsSource="{x:Bind areasForFilter, Mode=OneWay}"
        SelectionMode="None">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock
                    x:Name="dropAreaItemText"
                    Padding="7,5,7,5"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                    CanDrag="True"
                    DragEnter="SwapArea_Item_DragEnter"
                    DragLeave="SwapArea_Item_DragLeave"
                    DragOver="SwapArea_Item_DragOver"
                    FontSize="16"
                    PointerEntered="SwapArea_Item_PE"
                    PointerExited="SwapArea_Item_Px"
                    Text="{Binding}"
                    TextWrapping="Wrap" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,2,10,2" />
                <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="True" />
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFF5F18E" />
                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10,10,10,10" />
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                            <ListViewItemPresenter
                                DragEnter="SwapArea_Item_DragEnter"
                                DragLeave="SwapArea_Item_DragLeave"
                                DragOver="SwapArea_Item_DragOver" />
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListView>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code and you need to set **AllowDrop="True"** for your ListViewItemPresenter.

For more information, you can refer to the official documentation **[Drag and drop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/input/drag-and-drop#designate-an-item-in-a-listview-or-gridview-as-a-folder)**.

```
<ListViewItemPresenter AllowDrop="True"...>
```

Comment: Please check current [realtime visual tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1by3y.png), the main render of `ListViewItem` is `ListViewItemPresenter`, It's better setting ListViewItemPresenter AllowDrop as true than `TextBlock` right? And MSFT has provide complete  drag and drop code sample [here](https://github.com/microsoft/windows-universal-samples/tree/main/Samples/XamlDragAndDrop) that you could refer to

Comment: Thank you, Nico. It's better this way. I edited my answer, thank you for the suggestion. : )

Comment: Thank you both - Yes it looks like setting AllowDrop on either the TextBlock or LVP did what I needed - I will probably stick with it on the LVP though in case the size/margin of the TextBlock changes. Thanks again!